# How to change dimensions with getUserMedia on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, webrtc, getusermedia

Since Apple's iOS 11 `webRTC` and `getUserMedia` introduction, I'm able to get the camera's input to the `<video>` element, but can't use conventional methods to set its dimensions (`height` and `width`).

This works:

```
var constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: { facingMode: 'user' }
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(
    function success(stream) {
         video.srcObject = stream;
    }
);
```

This doesn't work (**only** on iOS), and no image is shown:

```
var constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: { facingMode: 'user', width: 306, height: 180 }
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(
    function success(stream) {
         video.srcObject = stream;
    }
);
```

The error message from `catch`:

> Invalid constraint

---

**Failed attempts:** setting `mandatory`, `ideal`, `minHeight` etc.

---

Is this a bug? Are there any known alternatives?

Comment: adding a `.catch(function(e) { console.error(e); })` might reveal what error is thrown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Safari. Bare values like `width: 306` are [supposed to mean `ideal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Parameters), but Safari appears to treat them like `exact`, and fails with an error unless it exactly matches a driver resolution offered by the user's camera.

Except for that, Safari appears to work like other browsers like Firefox and Edge, where the goal is to find best-match native resolutions offered by the camera.

So stick to ranges until Safari fixes this.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: {width: {min: 320, max: 640}}})
```

...or use common values with a fallback strategy:

```
try {
  await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: {width: 320}})
} catch(e) {
  await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: {width: 640}})
}
```

Comment: How can I work with ranges and still make sure the ratio will be 16:9?

Comment: See your other question. There's also `advanced` constraints, and the yet-to-be-implemented `aspectRatio` constraint.

Comment: Voted up, but cannot accept this answer since it does not resolve my problem, only further describes it.